# What should I do when my husband keeps on denying me in bed?

Tags: sex, husband-wife

It has been many months now, and my husband keeps on denying me in bed. I don't know why, he always says he is tired, and I end up crying alone because I feel rejected.  I swallowed my pride and ask for it, but he always refuses.  What should I do?

Comment: in islam wife has right and husband also has right (duty) to satisfy each other every time other want. 

this period should not has delay more that 3 months. check you all the time shave all of your body and use best perfume and use best women 's dress

Answer (score -1):

you have equal right over husband as he has over you
“Those who take an oath not to have sexual relation with their wives must wait for four months, then if they return (change their idea in this period), verily, Allaah is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful[al-Baqarah 2:226]

It was narrated that Ibn ‘Umar (may Allaah be pleased with him) used to say concerning eelaa’: “If the period of eelaa’ expires, then the husband has either to retain his wife in a handsome manner or to divorce her as Allaah has ordered” (al-Bukhaari, al-Talaaq, 4881)